# mysqli_fetch_array using a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

Ive got a pretty basic table named 'customers' with four columns:
ID (primary Auto Increment)
businessName
contactName
contactEmail

I call it with:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM customers");
```

and was using mysqli_fetch_array to display it on the page with a foreach loop:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{    
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($row as $value) {
        echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>";
    }
    echo "<td><a href='updateform.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "'>Edit</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Which gives you an array like:

```
Array ( [id] => 1 [businessName] => Microsoft [contactName] => Bill Gates [contactEmail] => bill@microsoft.com ) Array ( [id] => 2 [businessName] => Amazon [contactName] => Jeff Bezos [contactEmail] => jeff@amazon.com )
```

Is it possible to display results differently based on which column (technically now position in the array) they are in? I would like to make a

```
a href="mailto:bill@microsoft.com"
```

link when it gets to contactEmail.
What if I wanted to display just one key or value instead of using foreach?
It doesn't seem possible to call

```
$row['contactEmail']
```

in the foreach loop
which confuses me since below that I am able to create a link to

```
$row['id']
```

If anyone has any ideas how to do this, or if there is a better way to be displaying this information, I'm open to suggestions, as I'm not very good at programming, especially PHP.

Comment: `$row['contactEmail']` should work just fine. What error are you getting?

Comment: Check that you're writing `'contactEmail'` **exactly** as it's stored in database. It's case sensitive according to documentation.

Comment: Also you can try `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` [link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) which will definitely get you an array you can access elements in.

Comment: I'd probably get rid of that inner foreach, as you only have 4 columns - it'll be clearer to just explicitly write out what each column you're trying to display.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes! you can just add like this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{    
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        if($key == "contactEmail"){
          $mailUrl = "mailto:".$value;
          echo "<td><a href=".$mailUrl.">".$value."</a>";
        }
        else{
          echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>";
        }
    }
    echo "<td><a href='updateform.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "'>Edit</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can able to `mysqli_fetch_array` retrieve data directly using `foreach` loop. like bellow :

```
<?php
  $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM customers");
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Business Name</td>
        <td>Contact Name</td>
        <td>#</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {    
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$row['businessName']."</td>";       
            foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
                $newValue = $key == "contactEmail" ? '<a href="mailto:'.$mailUrl.'">'.$value.'</a>' : $value;
                echo "<td>" . $newValue . "</td>";         
            }
            echo "<td><a href='updateform.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "'>Edit</a></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    } 
    ?>
</table>
```